# updating a ScrolledText box with information from another class variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a ScrolledText widget in my GUI __init__ class. I need to populate it with information from a variable in another class, but that variable isn't populated with data until I run a different function.

the structure is as follows:

```
class main_window():
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        sctxt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.frame)

    def calculate_stuff(self):
        StuffClass.stuff = calculated_stuff
        # need to update the sctxt variable with StuffClass.stuff

class StuffClass():
    stuff = None
```

How do I do this. I've tried accessing the sctxt widget directly to use the sctxt.insert() method. But I"m stuck there.

I hope this was clear. If not, then I'll try to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an instance variable:

```
class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self.sctxt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.frame)

    def calculate_stuff(self):
        self.sctxt.insert('end', data)
```

This is very basic python ... you may want to run through a few python beginner tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for that, worked great. However, I'm a geologist, not a coder or programmer. I'm working on this as a side skill, I have a full time job that I"m actually decent at that doesn't involve coding.

Comment: If I asked you why mountains exist you'd probably tell me to take a beginner's geology class and come back with more specific questions. Similarly here we expect a bare minimum of python knowledge before asking questions. There are beginner's forums like learnpython.reddit.com if you don't have time to walk through a tutorial.

Comment: Well, to be fair. All I missed was the "self" in self.sctxt as I indicated in the original post that I was trying to access the variable and use the sctxt.insert() method. A better analogy would be you asking which event caused the upthrust of the front-ranges having already known how mountains were formed. But I'm sure you never make a typo or other mistakes. Thanks for your help again, but I've clearly taken a fair amount of intro tutorials or I would have been a lot further away from the solution on my own. One word missing, that's it, at 2am. Get over yourself.